# How do I clear the text field value after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys does someone of you know how to delete the text field after I click submit?

I have a button "senden" and after I click on this button the value of the text fields above should be deleted and the check box must be unchecked again.

I tried some tutorials but it didn' work.

Here is my code, if someone wants to help me

Comment: do you want to delete all inputs inside `<form id="send">`? why?

Comment: no the text input of " name, ort, datum" and the value of the checkbox

Comment: Side note: All inputs to be submitted in a form must be inside the `<form>` and `</form>`, as your checkbox is outside the form with id `send`.

Comment: Btw, it is never a good idea to use non-English variable/function/class names.

Comment: I know but my teacher said we should do it in german -.- I dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again with jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
     //Other code here

     //And end your function with this:
     $("#name").val("");
     $("#ort").val("");
     $("#datum").val("");
     $("input [name='Favorit']").prop("checked", false);

});
```

**EDIT:**

In order your checkbox to work, set an `id`, for example:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" id="Favorit" value="Favorit">Favorit </input>`

Afterwards target the checkbox with:

```
 $('#submit').click(function() {
 //Other code here

 //And end your function with this (after you gave the checkbox `id`):
 $("#name").val("");
 $("#ort").val("");
 $("#datum").val("");
 $("#Favorit").prop("checked", false);

 });
```

Comment: `input name['Favorit']` will match elements called `name` that have an *attribute* `Favorit` which are *descendants* of `input`.

Comment: Correct, it is better to give an `id` to this checkbox, since the OP does not provide such in his question

Comment: I assume you intended `input[name='Favorit']`.

Comment: `input [name='Favorit']` targets arbitrary elements with a `name` attribute whose value equals `'Favorit'` and which are ***descendant*** of an `input` element. A space in a selector is the **descendant selector**.

Comment: everything works except the checkbox :/ can yu maybe add a code snippet? :)

Comment: Read these comments and you know why the checkbox does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, run the snippet in this answer and see if it meets your requirement. You will find the changes I have done to your code delimited by `CHANGES` comment in the HTML and JavaScript code.

I hope it does and here are my observations:

1. Every input that you you want to be submitted (in a standard form submission) must be inside the `form` i.e. between the opening `<form>` and the closing `</form>`. Thus, I took the liberty of moving the checkbox inside the form. Kindly ensure this does not break your existing code.
2. I found client-side validation in your JavaScript code and added the input-clearing code at the end of the success case. To make the selection of input elements general (and currently limited to textbox and checkbox), I have added the form ID and a general input selector with type, as follows:

   `// clear the input fields if the form has been processed
   $('#send input[type="text"]').val('');
   $('#send input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var allArtists = [];


  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var $rowTemplate = $('<tr><td data-id="id"></td><td data-id="name"></td><td data-id="geburtsort"></td><td data-id="geburtsdatum"></td><td data-id="favorite"></td></tr>');

    var artistName = $("#name").val();
    var ort = $("#ort").val();
    var datum = $("#datum").val();
    var favourite = $("[name=Favorit]").is(':checked');
 

  if(artistName!= "" && ort != "" && datum != ""){
   $('.fehlermeldung').hide();
    allArtists.push([artistName, ort, datum]);

    var rowId = allArtists.length;

    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=id]').text(rowId);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=name]').text(artistName);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsort]').text(ort);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsdatum]').text(datum);
    var checked = favourite ? "checked" : "";
  
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=favorite]').html('<div class="chkText">'+favourite+'</div>').append($('<input type="checkbox" id="fave" ' + checked + '>'));
  
    $("#table tbody").append($rowTemplate);
// CHANGES START
// clear the input fields if the form has been processed
$('#send input[type="text"]').val('');
$('#send input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
// CHANGES END

  }else{
   $('.fehlermeldung').show();
  }

  });
  $("#table").on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
  $(this).prev('div').text($(this).is(":checked"));
});
  
};



function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.chkText{
  float:left;
  }
 .fehlermeldung{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Artist</title>
</head>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<body>
<div id="layout">
<h1>Künstler hinzufügen</h1>
<form id="send">
    <label>Add artists</label>
    <br>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name des Künstlers" />
    <br>

    <label>Ort</label>
    <br>
    <input id="ort" type="text" placeholder="Woher stammt der Künstler" />
    <br>

    <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
    <br>
    <input id="datum" type="text" placeholder="Wann ist der Künstler geboren?" />
    <br>
<!-- CHANGES START - moving the checkbox inside form -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" value="Favorit">Favorit </input>
<!-- CHANGES END -->

</form>

<!-- CHANGES START - removing checkbox from outside the form -->
<!--
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" value="Favorit">Favorit </input>
<p>
-->
<!-- CHANGES END -->

    <input type="button" id="submit" name="senden" value="Senden">
 <div class="fehlermeldung">
 <label id="fehler" style="color: #962d2d"> Bitte füllen Sie alle Zeilen aus!</label>
 </div>
<!-- CHANGES START -->
<br />
<!-- CHANGES END -->
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="     Search for names..">

<table id="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geburtsort</th>
        <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
  <div>
        <th>Favorit</th>
  </div>
    </tr>
    </tbody>


</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {

  //your codes  

  $("form#send").find('input:text').val('');

  // I reccomend to move all input from the same group inside <form> tag.
  //in this case, <button id=submit> and <input type=checkbox> should be
  //moved within form#send
  
  //$("form#send").find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
  //or
  $("input:checkbox[name='Favorit']").prop('checked', false);

  //set the focus
$("#send").find('input:text')[0].focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<form id="send">
  <label>Add artists</label>
  <br>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name des Künstlers" />
  <br>

  <label>Ort</label>
  <br>
  <input id="ort" type="text" placeholder="Woher stammt der Künstler" />
  <br>

  <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
  <br>
  <input id="datum" type="text" placeholder="Wann ist der Künstler geboren?" />
  <br>
  <!--better to keep this inside form-->
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" value="Favorit">Favorit</input>
  </p>
  <input type="button" id="submit" name="senden" value="Senden">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  window.onload = function() {
    var allArtists = [];


  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var $rowTemplate = $('<tr><td data-id="id"></td><td data-id="name"></td><td data-id="geburtsort"></td><td data-id="geburtsdatum"></td><td data-id="favorite"></td></tr>');

    var artistName = $("#name").val();
    var ort = $("#ort").val();
    var datum = $("#datum").val();
    var favourite = $("[name=Favorit]").is(':checked');


  if(artistName!= "" && ort != "" && datum != ""){
      $('.fehlermeldung').hide();
    allArtists.push([artistName, ort, datum]);

    var rowId = allArtists.length;

    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=id]').text(rowId);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=name]').text(artistName);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsort]').text(ort);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsdatum]').text(datum);
    var checked = favourite ? "checked" : "";

    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=favorite]').html('<div class="chkText">'+favourite+'</div>').append($('<input type="checkbox" id="fave" ' + checked + '>'));

     $("#table tbody").append($rowTemplate);
     //And end your function with this (after you gave the checkbox `id`):
     $("#name").val("");
     $("#ort").val("");
     $("#datum").val("");
     $("#Favorit").prop("checked", false);

  }else{
      $('.fehlermeldung').show();
  }
  });
  $("#table").on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
  $(this).prev('div').text($(this).is(":checked"));
});

};



function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
 .chkText{
          float:left;
          }
         .fehlermeldung{
             display: none;
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layout">
<h1>Künstler hinzufügen</h1>
<form id="send">
    <label>Add artists</label>
    <br>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name des Künstlers" />
    <br>

    <label>Ort</label>
    <br>
    <input id="ort" type="text" placeholder="Woher stammt der Künstler" />
    <br>

    <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
    <br>
    <input id="datum" type="text" placeholder="Wann ist der Künstler geboren?" />
    <br>
</form>

<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" value="Favorit">Favorit </input>
<p>

    <input type="button" id="submit" name="senden" value="Senden">
    <div class="fehlermeldung">
    <label id="fehler" style="color: #962d2d"> Bitte füllen Sie alle Zeilen aus!</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="     Search for names..">

<table id="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geburtsort</th>
        <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
        <div>
        <th>Favorit</th>
        </div>
    </tr>
    </tbody>


</table>
</div>
```